# select user doesn't contain a record in other table sql query

Tags: sql, record

I had three tables: sarcuser, sarcusercommittee, sarcallcourse. I need to build a query that brings all the users that don't have a committee (they don't have a record in sarcusercommittee). Here is my current query:

```
SELECT        u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname AS name, u.dateofbirth, u.gender, LEFT(u.note, 200) AS note, c.name AS coursename
FROM            sarcuser AS u INNER JOIN
                         sarcusercommittee AS uc ON u.id = uc.user_id INNER JOIN
                         sarcallcourse AS c ON c.id = u.courseid
WHERE        ((SELECT        COUNT(id) AS Expr1
                            FROM            sarcusercommittee
                            WHERE        (user_id = u.id)) = 0)
ORDER BY name DESC
```

I guess the problem is in (ON condistion) but don't get it ... any help ? 
NOTE : I use visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT          u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname AS name, u.dateofbirth, u.gender, LEFT(u.note, 200) AS note, c.name AS coursename
FROM            sarcuser AS u 
INNER JOIN      sarcallcourse AS c 
ON              c.id = u.courseid
WHERE           u.id NOT IN (
    SELECT      uc.user_id
    FROM        sarcusercommittee AS uc
)
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Firstly you shouldn't inner join onto `sarcusercommittee` if you dont want rows from it. Seconly I would filter to the users that are not in `sarcusercommittee` using `NOT IN`.

Comment: I thought in that ... but didn't really know how to do it ... thanks

Comment: You can use the query example I provided